# ASP.NET core - Change the server name dynamically

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm trying to change the server like string interpolation.

`appsettings.Development.json` file:

```
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "DefaultConnection": "Server=${ServerName};${DataBaseName};Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
    },
    "ServerName": "(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb,
    "DataBaseName": "Database=proj-Final000"
        "Logging": {
            "LogLevel": {
                "Default": "Information",
                "Microsoft": "Warning",
                "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
            }
        }
    }
```

I have tried with user `config["ServerName"]` with no luck.

Can anyone help me figure out how can I make it work? And why it doesn't work this way?

Comment: It doesn't work because it's a JSON file, not a C# string that that will get compiled. What you're probably looking for, is overrides in the form of `appsettings.${environment}.json`, where you change the ConnectionStrigns.DefaultConnection per environment.

Comment: @CodeCaster So basically there is no way to declare a property at the appsettings.Development.json file such as DataBaseName or ServerName

Comment: @CodeCaster I have edited the code slightly

Comment: There is, but you'll have to do the parsing and replacing yourself. And if you have a dependency that takes a connection string **name**, which it'll use to look up the connection string, it won't run your logic. Any reason why you won't go with environment-specific config files?